# Timeout for fsockopen?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to set the timeout of fsockopen? I set 5 in the @fsockopen line but it seems much shorter when it fails?

```
$socket = @fsockopen(Config::get('client.host'), Config::get('client.port'), $errno, $errstr, 5);

if (!$socket) { 
    return false;

} 
else {
    fclose($socket);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: remove the `@` at `@fsockopen`. Enclose it in an `if` statement and handle the possible error: `if(!$socket = fsockopen(...)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The timeout parameter sets the **maximum** time a function should block.

If an error occurs, the function can return way before it hit the timeout.

Examine the `$errno`/`$errstr` variables to diagnose the problem.